# c# - the variable is assigned but its value is never used

Tags: c#

```
private void btnHasil_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rataipa = Convert.ToInt32(NIPA.Text);
        int uipa, uipa1, uipa2, uipa3, uipa4;

        if ((rataipa >= 61) && (rataipa <= 69))
        {
            uipa1 = (70 - rataipa) / 10;
            uipa2 = (rataipa - 60) / 12;
        }
        else if ((rataipa == 60) && (rataipa >= 70) && (rataipa <= 72))
        {
            uipa2 = (rataipa - 60) / 12;
        }
        else if ((rataipa >= 76) && (rataipa <= 84))
        {
            uipa3 = (85 - rataipa) / 13;
            uipa4 = (rataipa - 75) / 10;
        }
        else if ((rataipa >= 72) && (rataipa <= 75) || (rataipa == 85))
        {
            uipa3 = (85 - rataipa) / 13;
        }
        else
            uipa = 1;
    }
```

i try to build the errors shows in variable uipa and it shows the variable 'uipa' is assigned but its value is never used but i used it after that and now i don't know how to fix. anyone can help ?

Comment: Assign an initialization value. 
`int uipa = 0, uipa1, uipa2, uipa3, uipa4;`

Comment: The problem is that *all* of those variables are defined within the scope of that method.  Once you exit the method, they cease to exist.  So the error message is correct: it's value is never used.  Do you have another `uipa` defined elsewhere that you are using?

Comment: it's only defined in there

Comment: @KanigaraPutra The warning tells you everything about the problem. There isn't really another way to say it. "the variable is assigned but its value is never used". So, either don't assign a value to the variable (since it doesn't achieve anything), or write code to use the value you've set. Your current method appears to do nothing at all (Except for throwing an exception if `NIPA` is not an integer).

Answer (score 1):

You assign `uipa` at the very end of the code but then you never actually do anything with it.

```
else uipa = 1;
```

To remove the warning, you need to do something with `uipa` or remove the above statement entirely.  As far as the compiler is concerned, `uipa` serves no purpose.

If you do decide to use `uipa` later in say an `if` statement, be sure to initialise `uipa` to some *default value* too else you will run into a different warning about **unitialised variables**.

```
int uipa = 0, ....;  // initialise uipa here to a default value
.
.
.
else uipa = 1;

if (uipa ==1) // this will solve the variable is assigned but never used problem
{
    // do something 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int rataipa = Convert.ToInt32(NIPA.Text);
    int uipa, uipa1, uipa2, uipa3, uipa4;
    if ((rataipa >= 61) && (rataipa <= 69))
    {
        uipa1 = (70 - rataipa) / 10;
        uipa2 = (rataipa - 60) / 12;
    }
    else if ((rataipa == 60) && (rataipa >= 70) && (rataipa <= 72))
    { uipa2 = (rataipa - 60) / 12; }
    else if ((rataipa >= 76) && (rataipa <= 84))
    {
        uipa3 = (85 - rataipa) / 13;
        uipa4 = (rataipa - 75) / 10;
    }
    else if ((rataipa >= 72) && (rataipa <= 75) || (rataipa == 85))
    { uipa3 = (85 - rataipa) / 13; }
    else 
    {         //add this bracket
     uipa = 1;
    }
```

Comment: i already add but in line `int uipa`, varibale uipa still shows error

Comment: This doesn't address the question.  Warning remains during compilation